# How do I get this body armour located in Tomb Of Ramses III?

Tags: serious-sam-hd-the-first-encounter

I'm at the Tomb Of Ramses III in Serious Sam HD, and there is some body armour located at the top of an area previously containing an Arachnoid. I'm unable to find anyway up to this area.

[image]

How do I get up to that area, and retrieve the body armour?

Comment: I know I've gotten that armor before... there *is* a passage up there, or possibly to higher up and you need to jump down to reach it.

Comment: I remember getting it too. I want to say that there's some passage that gets you to the back column of the left side of that screenshot, but its been years since I played the game. If you don't have an answer in about 12 hours, I may play through just to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have a screenshot for you because I didn't feel like booting windows and finding the right savegame. However, to your back are some steps. **Locate the red/white + Box upstairs and go right of it past the rightmost pillar (hidden doorway).** You get into a room with some extra goodies which has a normal (non-hidden) passage to the balusters you can see from your current position (on the picture). Then you're practically there.

If this was still too fuzzy, I found a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_wehXR-anc) that shows where to go exactly (everything is cluttered with text for some reason and it's black/white, but it gets the general idea across).